# Skip adding duplicates from one listbox to another

Tags: vb.net, listbox, listboxitems

I have the following code:

```
  'get the items from listbox4
       For Each aa As String In ListBox4.Items
        'convert string to uri and grap the hostname for each item in listbox4
        Dim myuri As New Uri(aa)
        Dim baseUri As String = myuri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
        ' check if the hostname exist on items of listbox2 and skip the duplicate
            If ListBox2.Items.Contains(baseUri) Then
                Return
            Else
                ListBox2.Items.Add(aa)
            End If
        Next
```

How can I make the second ListBox contain distinct values, based on the data from the first ListBox?

Comment: what is not working? any errors?

Comment: Instead of **return** you may like to use **Continue For** in order to check the next item instead of jumping out of the whole For-Each-Loop. Or alternatively you can **If Not ListBox2.Items.Contains(baseUrI) Then ListBox2.Items.Add(aa)** and just do not care about the else

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Linq base method (treat as pseudo-code, I didn't have time to test it on a working solution):

```
ListBox2.Items.AddRange( _
    ListBox4.Items.Select( _
        Function(x) new Uri(x).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)).Distinct() _
) ' End AddRange
```

Basically, it adds a range of items selected from ListBox4 where a new Uri is selected using each element, then the Uri is modified with your method, and then selects the distinct string representation of the modified uri.

Answer (score 0):

Clear listbox2 before starting the loop. Inside the loop, change "Return" to "Continue"